# Is 'there is' grammatically correct in this sentence?

Tags: grammaticality

Is 'there is' grammatically correct in this sentence?

> 1. There is currently no available on large-scale solution that ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"There is" is perfectly valid in that sentence.

The primary grammatical problem with that sentence is the extra "on":

> There is currently no available <strike>on</strike> large-scale solution that ...

*Large-scale* is a modifier to *solution*, and does not need a preposition to introduce it.

As pointed out elsewhere, you may also wish to simplify the sentence depending on what you want to emphasize.  As written, the words *currently* and *available* serve to give the impression that at some not-too-distant time, a suitable solution may become available.  If you remove those words, you remove that impression as well:

> There is no large-scale solution that ...

This reads as a blanket statement, implying that such a solution may in fact be impossible.

If *large scale* is intended to refer to how available the solution is, rather than to the capability of the solution itself, then the sentence needs to be reworded to clearly apply the modifier to the correct element:

> There is currently no solution available on a large scale that ...

Comment: This answer makes the same assumption that in this part of the statement (which the questioner has not asked about) the largeness of scale refers (poorly) to the solution, and not (reasonably) to the availability.

Comment: A valid point, which I had not considered.  I will edit.

Answer (score 0):

I would more likely say:

*There is no large-scale solution that...*

or

*Currently, there is no large scale solution...*

or you could do it in plural:

*There are currently no solutions that...*

It is worth mentioning that you can drop 'currently' entirely and not really change the meaning. There is/are are both present tense and so 'currently' is assumed.

Comment: Reasonable, however an *available on large-scale solution* is not necessarily the same as a *large scale solution*, and you may be losing a deliberate subtlety in the original statement by changing it in that way.

Comment: I am unclear what is meant by an "available on large scale solution". If it is not a specific piece of jargon, it just does not parse correctly.

Comment: A solution available on (a) large scale, as opposed a large scale solution, i.e. large in some other measure, size of business served perhaps. It would possibly benefit from the addition of an "a" (on a large scale) to my ear, but I can imagine it being perfectly serviceable in its business domain, though I wouldn't say it was a specific piece of jargon as such.

Answer (score -1):

If an *available on large-scale solution* is a thing, and there currently isn't one that... whatever, then yes, *there is (currently no)* is perfectly fine.

Answer (score -2):

"There is" is incorrect. Where is the "there" you reference?

How about:

- No large-scale solution exists to....
- A large-scale solution to _____ does not yet exist.